# Take latest commits from multiple repos then merge into another single repo without creating a new repo

Tags: git

As per the requirement we have got mutliple repo containing many projects and have merged these into single repo which contains all the projects which exists in multiple repo.
I have done merged these into single repo and it contains all the commits till the merged date. After the merge ,Single repo doesn't contain those new commits present in multiple repo.

My question is

1)How can we pick the latest commits from multiple repo

2)If it is possible to pick those commits how it could be merged to single repo

Have tried with cherry-picking but it creates the new commit id which differs from that of multiple repo commit id that should not happen in our case.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). But your "final" repo will be updated with the new commits on sub repos so I don't know if it's what you want to do.

I may have another solution :

- make a new git repo `git init`
- add remotes for each repo you want to add `git remote add origin1 http://myurl.com`
- add all files for all remotes : `git checkout origin1/master -- .`

I'm not sure if it will work but I will definitely try out

Comment: Thanks for your advice...but it did not gave solution to my problem The scenario is as below:
Consider test.git is multiple repo which has got many projects (Ex:ProjectA..each project one repo)under it and 
merged test.git into single repo named XYZ.git(one repo many projects)
After merge there are some new commits to the multiple repo(test.git).
How can we pick these latest commits from multiple repo and do merge to single repo(XYZ.git).
While merging commit history should not get changed.

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Did you took a look at submodules ?, it seems it might be what you need

Comment: @deepthi You should really consider DARK_DUCK's advice regarding submodules. From your description it's exactly what you need.